# Python3 Regex for extract digits

Tags: python, regex, parsing, digits

I try to extract digits from urls with Python.

```
import re

url = '/randomtext/02@randomtext/01@randomtext/03@randomtext/01@.mp4'
for m in re.finditer(r'\d{2}', url):
    print(m[0], end='')
```

print function do this but I need the same result in variable, how can I did this?

Comment: What do you mean by the same result in variable?

Comment: do you want the output like this joined together like this 
'02010301'

Comment: I need the same result  '02010301'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "".join(m[0] for m in re.finditer(...))
```

Comment: Thanks
That is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `re.sub` with an empty string as the replacement. That pattern should be fine.

```
url = '/randomtext/02@randomtext/01@randomtext/03@randomtext/01@.mp4'
print(re.sub(r'\d{2}', '', url))
```

Prints:

```
/randomtext/@randomtext/@randomtext/@randomtext/@.mp4
```

Comment: That is not the same what I need. I need 02010301 as result. Thanks anyway.